# Custom menu deletes itself

Tags: menus

I've set up a menu on one of my sites. The menu has ~30 items. Everything is fine, but at some point the menu crops itself and displays only the first 12 item. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to tackle this issue?

Comment: This could possibly be a memory issue if you have a complex menu structure. What hosting environment are using? I've had this happen when saving a large menu on a weak server.

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue. I have a dedicated  virtual server for this site. I wonder if it has something to do with php.ini or WP itself, though...

Comment: Are you using the Wordpress Menu UI or are you using a function?

Comment: I'm using the menu UI. with wp_nav_manu. Damn, this is so wierd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it will help, but here is sort of what you are talking about:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134

Try adding:

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
```

to your php.ini